# LKM linux_dirent implementation

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel

As an exercise (security research) I'm trying to implement a wrapped system call. According to getdents documentation - you have to implement your own linux_dirent struct (https://linux.die.net/man/2/getdents64). This all seems to work but I am unable to read the linux_dirent name correctly.

Implementation of linux_dirent:

```
struct mylkm_linux_dirent {
    u64            d_ino;
    s64            d_off;
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    char           d_name[];
};
```

Wrapped getdents() call:

```
/*
This method will call the original and then sift through results.
Method will remove results that contain the specified keyword.
*/
asmlinkage long mylkm_getdents(unsigned int fd, struct mylkm_linux_dirent * dirp, unsigned int count)
{
    unsigned int size = 0;
    unsigned int bpos = 0;
    struct mylkm_linux_dirent* dir1 = NULL;
    char * buffer_ptr = NULL;
    char hide[] = "mylkm";

    printk("mylkm: getdents() called - redirecting to original sys call.\n");
    size = (*k_getdents)(fd, dirp, count);
    printk("mylkm: bytes value returned by original getdents() call: %ld\n", size);
    printk("mylkm: count value passed into original getdents() call: %i\n", count);
    printk("mylkm: dirp pointer value: %p\n", dirp);

    for (bpos = 0; bpos<size;)
    {
        buffer_ptr = (char*)(&dirp + bpos);
        dir1 = (struct mylkm_linux_dirent*)buffer_ptr;
        printk("mylkm: record length: %d\n", dir1->d_reclen);
        printk("mylkm: record name: %s\n", dir1->d_name);
        printk("mylkm: offset to next dirent: %lld\n", (long long)dir1->d_off);

        bpos += dir1->d_reclen;
    }

    printk("mylkm: Completed mylkm_getdents() call\n");
    return 0;
}
```

log output:

```
[ 1383.082213] mylkm: LKM v0.1 has been loaded.
[ 1389.397196] mylkm: getdents() called - redirecting to original sys call.
[ 1389.397207] mylkm: bytes value returned by original getdents() call: 496
[ 1389.397208] mylkm: count value passed into original getdents() call: 32768
[ 1389.397209] mylkm: dirp pointer value: 0000000002075370
[ 1389.397209] mylkm: record length: 65152
[ 1389.397210] mylkm: record name: \xffffffff\xffffffff\xffffffff\xffffffff\xffffffff\xffffffff
[ 1389.397210] mylkm: offset to next dirent: 34034544
[ 1389.397211] mylkm: Completed mylkm_getdents() call
```

I've tried explicitly casting the dir1->d_name to a char pointer. Passing in a char pointer into the original call crashes. How do I get the correct listing?

Comment: `buffer_ptr = (char*)(&dirp + bpos);` - Is this ever compiles with `dirp` being a *pointer to a struct*, so a structure is added with a number? At the right you probably want `((char*)dirp) + bpos` which firstly converts pointer to the pointer-to-char, and then makes an arithmetic with it.

Comment: In `for` cycle add output of `dir1` pointer. And check it being consistent with `dirp` argument of the syscall (that is, on the first iteration `dir1` should be equal to `dirp`; on every next iteration `dir1` should be equal to its previous value plus previous record length).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I agree... the program crashes with ((char*)dirp) + bpos. The same with trying to cast the pointer to a (struct mylkm_linux_dirent *).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I will check that. I am also going to manually increment the pointer position and try and get to the reclen and name variables (4 bytes for u long and 2 for u short).

Comment: reclen = dirp + bpos + 8;
name = dirp + bpos + 10;
printk("mylkm: record length: %d\n", reclen);
printk("mylkm: record name: %s\n", name); The print out of the char * name variable crashes. reclen was successful.

Comment: Expression `dirp + bpos + 8` interprets `dirp` as **array** of `struct mylkm_linux_dirent` elements, and return element of that array at index `bpos + 8`. It doesn't return field at given offset. No needs to use arithmetic for compute the structure's fields. I asked you only to check the pointer to the structure, which fields you use. BTW, you may print fields of the first dentry just using `dirp` pointer: `dirp->d_reclen`, `dirp->d_name`.

Comment: As you mentioned earlier - using &dirp and the pointer values dont match. Using ((char*dirp)+bpos and the pointer values match, with only one iteration of the loop. A call to dirp->d_reclen crashes the module. It seems like the implementation of linux_dirent is not correct?

Comment: `It seems like the implementation of linux_dirent is not correct?` - The syscall implementation is out of the game: `dirp` is an *input parameter* for the syscall, and the syscall cannot affect on availability of the memory pointed by `dirp`. Of course, the accessibility of the memory is checked inside the syscall. But returning positive value means that the memory is accessible. From the other side, the memory is a **user-space memory**, so a kernel code shoudn't *directly* access it. While direct accessing works sometimes, proper way is to use `copy_from_user` for read.

Comment: Interesting - I'm going to try copy_from_user.

Comment: I got a chance to test this. The copy_from_user worked! Thanks Tsyvarev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is:

1. Using proper *pointer arithmetic* for get elements of the `dirp` array. E.g.

   ```
   buffer_ptr = ((char*)dirp) + bpos;
   dir1 = (struct mylkm_linux_dirent*)buffer_ptr;
   ```
2. Access the array's elements via `copy_from_user` function, not directly. E.g.

   ```
   u64 reclen; # Record length will be stored here
   get_user(&reclen, &dir1->d_reclen); # TODO: check possible errors
   printk("mylkm: record length: %d\n", reclen);

   # Allocate a structure in the kernel
   struct mylkm_linux_dirent* dir1_kernel = kmalloc(reclen, GFP_KERNEL); # TODO: check possible errors
   # and copy user-space structure into it.
   copy_from_user(dir1_kernel, dir1, reclen); # TODO: check possible errors

   # Use dir1_kernel instead of dir
   printk("mylkm: record name: %s\n", dir1_kernel->d_name);

   # Free kernel structure at the end of the loop
   kfree(dir1_kernel);
   ```